# How to add graphics to a coded football game

Tags: python-3.x

I have already made a game where you type in what play you want to do and based on a probability you get an outcome. This is one of the plays of my code.

```
if usinp == "yes" or "Yes":
print ("You are playing the Packers in OT of the 2014 NFC championship game.")
firplay = input("It's your ball on the Seattle 13. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? HB gut, Hail Mary, or WR screen pass? \n")
if firplay == "HB gut":
    import random
    _1 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
    _2 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
    _3 = "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
    _4 = "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
    _5 = "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
    _6 = "Ah, Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"
    _7 = "Ah, Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"
    _8 = "Ah, Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"
    _9 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
    _10 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"

    PossibleOutcomes = [_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10]
    mychoice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
    print(mychoice)  
    if "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == mychoice:
        print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

    elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" == mychoice:
        _2play = input ("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Stop and go, or Hook and ladder?")

    else:
        print("You would be a horrible head coach your team will never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")
```

What I want to add is it shows the outcome that the player got on the screen with moving graphics and players.

Comment: You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The 2014 NFC Championship! I agree with the comment from RussellB, can you please edit this into a [mcve]?